# Definitively delete the tracking of .DS_Store files in GIT

Tags: git

I've a git repo where `.DS_Store` files are already tracked. Is there a way to completely ignore theme in every folder?

I know that before being tracked I can simply put `.DS_Store` in `.gitignore`, but I also know that it doesn't work if `.DS_Store` are already versioned.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to remove them from the repo using `git rm` and then commit the changes.

```
git rm --cached "*.DS_Store"
git commit -m "remove all .DS_Store"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove them in some way or another, using `git rm`. Of course, this may be easier than going through them manually:

```
find -name .DS_Store -print0 | xargs -0 git rm
```